# Pick a random element from a JSON or XML list inside a Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, xml, random

This is a simplification of the code that I am using.

```html
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
var human = [

 
  {
            name: ["John","Peter","Sarah","Rose"],
            age: ["20","25","30"],
   nacionality: ["American","Welsh","Scotish","English"],
   country: ["USA","England","Wales","Scotland"],

  },

        {
        name: ["Renzo","Andrea","Monica","Tina"],
        age: ["20","25","30"],
  nacionality: ["Italian"],
  country: ["USA","England","Wales","Scotland"],

 },
    ],

    total = human.length,
    boton = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0],
    parrafo = document.getElementsByTagName("p")[0];
 
    var p = Math.floor(Math.random() * total),
        pTotal = human[p].name.length,
        c = Math.floor(Math.random() * pTotal);
     cTotal = human[p].age.length,
  ci=Math.floor(Math.random() *cTotal);
  ciTotal = human[p].nacionality.length,
  a=Math.floor(Math.random() *ciTotal);
  aTotal = human[p].country.length,
  cii=Math.floor(Math.random() *aTotal);
 
 document.write('Name: ' + human[p].name[c] +"</br>Age: "+ human[p].age[ci] + "</br>Nacionality: " + human[p].nacionality[a] +"</br>Country: " + human[p].country[cii]); 
</SCRIPT>
```

I'm going to have many rings like these. And some, for example country, I would like to choose from a single external list. I do not want to have to change each ring individually.

I will not work with server, nor with PHP. I need to choose that element from a JSON or from an XML.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What you are doing doesn't make sense - get a random name and then assign some random values to it. What do you mean by "rings"?

Comment: Thanks for answering Jeff.

When I say "rings", I mean the array that associates the different variables (name, age, etc.) As I said before, for example country, it is the same information. And if I had 50 rings and had to add or remove a country, it seems more practical to do it from a single external list.

You know what I mean now?

Comment: So you want to edit your file contents and save the results back to the file. Using JavaScript - you can read a file, manipulate the object but you can not save it back. Depending upon the final file format you can use a JSON editor or XML editor.

Comment: I would like to have a JSON or XML file that contains the category "countries" and call it from javascript. The idea is that Javascript randomly choose one of the elements of the list.

Answer (score 0):

I've changed your property names to plural, so that they reflect the fact that we're dealing with a list of some sort.

```js
function sample(arr){
  return arr.length? 
    arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)]: 
    undefined;
}

var humans = [
  {
    names: ["John", "Peter", "Sarah", "Rose"],
    ages: ["20", "25", "30"],
    nationalities: ["American", "Welsh", "Scotish", "English"],
    countries: ["USA", "England", "Wales", "Scotland"],
  },

  {
    names: ["Renzo", "Andrea", "Monica", "Tina"],
    ages: ["20", "25", "30"],
    nationalities: ["Italian"],
    countries: ["USA", "England", "Wales", "Scotland"],
  },
];

var group = sample(humans);
container.innerHTML = [
  "Name: " +        sample(group.names),
  "Age: " +         sample(group.ages),
  "Nacionality: " + sample(group.nationalities),
  "Country: " +     sample(group.countries)
].join("<br>");
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the contribution Thomas. Would you know how to make JavaScript choose a random element from an external JSON or XML list?

Comment: @user3313351 the same way. Or are you asking how to load JSON/XML from a file?

Comment: Exactly. How do I load a JSON/XML list for Javascript choose a specific category randomly? Only "countries" for example